# Calculate total price for each recipe in a Multi dimensional Array PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to work out how to:

- Display the name of each recipe and list the ingredients.
- Display the cost of each recipe.
- Display the total cost of all recipes.

  The problem is I can't get the total for each recipe (Super Energy Mix & Super Fruit Punch), my solution does not work properly to get the totals. Do I need another loop?

  ```
  $recipes = array(
   'Super Energy Mix' => array(
      'Sugar' => array('quantity' =>'1', 'price' => '1.15'),
      'Chocolate' => array('quantity' =>'1', 'price' => '2.10'),
      'Squash' => array('quantity' =>'1', 'price' => '1.35'),
      'Coffee' => array('quantity' =>'1', 'price' => '3.54')
  ),
  'Super Fruit Punch' => array(
      'Rum' => array('quantity' =>'1', 'price' => '3.52'),
      'Vodka' => array('quantity' =>'1', 'price' => '3.53'),
      'Orange Juice' => array('quantity' =>'1', 'price' => '1.35'),
      'Lime'  => array('quantity' =>'1', 'price' => '1.35')
  )
  ```

  );

  ```
   $sum = '0';

   foreach($recipes as $recipe => $key)
    {
     echo $recipe."<br/>";

     foreach($key as $keys => $value)
      {   
        echo $keys;
        echo $value['price']."<br/>"; 
        $sum += $value['price'];
      }
      echo $sum."<br/>";
    }
  ```

Comment: Move `$sum = '0';` within the first loop.

Comment: btw in your code you don't take into account the quantity. It doesn't change with these data but you need to include it no?

Comment: The data regarding quantity would be beneficial at a later date, at the moment I'm trying to get the total for each recipe and then the total cost for both recipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you are only resetting the sum at the start, so the total is for everything so far.

Move the setting of `$sum` into the loop so it gets reset for each recipe.

This version also multiplies the price by the quantity - not sure if you need this, but may be important at some point, but remove it if you don't need it.

```
$totalCost = 0;
foreach($recipes as $recipe => $key)
{
    echo $recipe."<br/>";
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($key as $keys => $value)
    {
        echo $keys;
        echo $value['price']."<br/>";
        $sum += ($value['price']*$value['quantity']);
    }
    echo $sum."<br/>";
    $totalCost += $sum;
}

echo "Total cost=".$totalCost."<br/>";
```

Added in total cost as per comment in question.

Comment: This is a great help and your input valued.

Answer (score 1):

Unsetting the `$sum` variable will correct your problem. I also removed `$sum = '0';` since it's not necessary to tell PHP a variable is zero. I also made minor adjustments to your code to make the text on the page a little easier to read.

```
 foreach($recipes as $recipe => $key)
  {
   echo '<strong>' . $recipe . "</strong><br/>";

   foreach($key as $keys => $value)
    {
      echo $keys . ': ';
      echo $value['price']."<br/>";
      $sum += $value['price'];
    }
    echo $sum."<br/>";
    unset($sum);
  }
```

Comment: Un-setting the $sum variable causes $sum in the second loop to become undefined, this is a really helpful explanation by the way.

Comment: @Justin strange. it doesn't happen when I execute it in my test environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can also build new items in your array inside the foreach.
That way you can easily get subtotals and totals of each recipe.

```
Foreach($recipes as &$recipe){
    Foreach($recipes as &$val){
        $val['subtotal'] = $val['quantity'] * $val['price'];
     }
     $recipe['total'] = array_sum(array_column($recipe, 'subtotal'));
 }

 $recipes['total'] =array_sum(array_column($recipes, 'total'));
Var_dump($recipes);
```

https://3v4l.org/boMES